# Not able to import url launcher package in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have added the package in my specs file but when i write import package than it is not importing url launcher file it is mentioning it as a unused file

Comment: Please provide the code you're using.

Comment: Please add code as well as the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**

I think they have a good documentation on how you can use their package, please see:
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher#-readme-tab-

**What you can do**

1. Check your internet connection, and ensure that retrieving dependencies is 100% successful.

Get Dependencies

```sh
flutter packages get
```

2. Given that you mentioned that it has a warning of "unused file", maybe you should actually use it.

Example usage

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _launchURL,
        child: Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://flutter.dev';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

**Furthermore**

Do you mind sharing a snippet of your code where you will use this? Also, please attach the code for your `pubspec.yaml` as well if deemed necessary.